# How to split filename and extension

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a following string:

```
string ImgName="Image.jpg";
```

I want to split the word from "." and save file name and extension in separate string.

Because in my database I want to save file name and its extension name in two different fields.

Comment: what part do you want ?

Comment: I want to trim the entire word after "."

Comment: That's not "trim", that's just a substring operation...

Comment: you wants to split your file name and extension not trimming.

Comment: Does your code compile alright? Shouldn't you be using double quotes?

Answer (score 41):

You can use `System.IO.Path` class:

```
var ext  = Path.GetExtension(filename);
var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
```

Comment: Its a very good solution if developer read file from path. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps, OP ought to convert the string into a [Path](http://www.dotnetperls.com/path) if obtained otherwise anyways? Any reason to not do that?

Answer (score 6):

**Solution 1 :** if you have only one dot in you filename the you can use the `String.Split()` function

Try This:

```
string ImgName = "Image.jpg";
var name = ImgName.Split('.');

String filename=name[0];
String fileext=name[1];
```

OR

**Solution 2 :** if you have multiple dots(or one dot ) in your filename you can use the `Substring()` function as below:

Try This:

```
string ImgName = "Image.jpg";
int lastIndex = ImgName.LastIndexOf('.');
var name = ImgName.Substring(0,lastIndex);
var ext = ImgName.Substring(lastIndex + 1);
```

Comment: Just go for the second solution: there is no need to scan the path to choose what solution to use, when both of them already performs a similar scan to accomplish their goals.

Answer (score 1):

```
string ImgName = "Image.jpg";
string name = new string(ImgName.TakeWhile(c => c != '.').ToArray());
string extension = new string(ImgName.SkipWhile(c => c != '.').Skip(1).ToArray());
```

Comment: why Linq ? Do you have resources to waste ? Moreover, this solution does not work if the path contains more than one dot.